# Chaining activities inside a tab

Tags: android

Here's my problem:
I've have an application with tabs.
in each tab I have a list that list to an other list then to a screen with an image, clickable text etc. 
In one word I have Tasks inside tabs.

Question 
Despite long seek among forum and tutorials I still can't figure witch is the best pactice to do that : switching activity insde a tab 
or changing the view.

Here my code

```
public class App extends TabActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Activity0.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("0").setIndicator("0",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_0))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Activity1.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("1").setIndicator("1", 
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_1))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

then I have to switch activities (Activity0 -> Activity01) inside tab 0

```
public class Activity0 extends Activity{
..
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainlist);
        ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

        l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
//          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You clciked "+parentTypes.get(arg2).getLibelle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            /*TODO database method */
            TypeEvenement parent = parentTypes.get(arg2);   
            if (parent.getChildren().size()!=0)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(TypeParentList.this, TypeChildList.class);
                int id= new Long(parentTypes.get(arg2).getId()).intValue();
                i.putExtra("typeid", id);

                View view = lam.startActivity("TypeChildList",i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)).getDecorView(); 

                setContentView(view);
```

then go back to this activity from Activity01

```
public class Activity01 extends Activity{
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(TypeChildList.this, Activity0.class);
                    LocalActivityManager lam = pa.getLocalActivityManager();


                    View view2 = lam.startActivity("Activity0",i).getDecorView(); 
                    setContentView(view2);

              }
              });
```

After go and back I get an error java.lang.IllegalStateException The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

I know it comes from my view but I can't figure out how to fix it 
So is this the best practice to do multiple activity in one tab ?

Please help needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `ViewSwitcher` or `ViewFlipper` you can keep the `View` attached to that and switch back and forth to your hearts desire.

Comment: I've done it by replacing the view eg the adapter like you suggest

Comment: Any chance of a sample superseed?

Answer (score 0):

One approach with a tab bar or a common shortcut bar is to have a separate class to handle the OnClickListeners that call startActivity(newIntent) and finish() back to back.  I'm not too fond of what the default TabView looks like, so I tend to make a graphical toolbar and use this approach.